# Cannot running AutomationTesting on Server Red Hat using jenkins

Tags: maven, selenium, jenkins, appium, redhat

In local server i tested using the same code it's work fine. But when i running in Red Hat Server this error appear. in this case my Red Hat server doesn't have internet connection is it necessary has internet on the red hat server? and than what needs to install appium server in Red Hat Server
using jdk 1.8.0 & maven 3.2.2

pom.xml

```
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>AutomationTest</groupId>
  <artifactId>AutomationTest</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>AutomationTest</name>

  <dependencies>

  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>

  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>                
             <groupId>junit</groupId>                               
             <artifactId>junit</artifactId>                             
             <version>3.8.1</version>                               
             <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>   

    <dependency>                
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>                               
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>                             
            <version>6.8.8</version>                                
            <scope>test</scope>                                     
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.01</version>
        </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testngFullTest.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

<pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>central</id>
          <name>Central Repository</name>
          <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
          <layout>default</layout>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
          <releases>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
          </releases>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

<repositories>
 <repository>
   <id>central</id>
   <name>Central Repository</name>
   <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
   <layout>default</layout>
   <snapshots>
      <enabled>false</enabled>
   </snapshots>
 </repository>
</repositories>

</project>
```

**Output**

```
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
Executing Maven:  -B -f /u01/Jenkins/home/workspace/Test1/AutomationTest/pom.xml clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building AutomationTest 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ AutomationTest ---
[INFO] Deleting /u01/Jenkins/home/workspace/Test1/AutomationTest/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ AutomationTest ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /u01/Jenkins/home/workspace/Test1/AutomationTest/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ AutomationTest ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ AutomationTest ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /u01/Jenkins/home/workspace/Test1/AutomationTest/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ AutomationTest ---
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /u01/Jenkins/home/workspace/Test1/AutomationTest/target/test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) @ AutomationTest ---
```

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[JENKINS] Recording test results
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 02:12 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-05-04T15:57:56+07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 31M/705M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

```
** ERROR **
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project AutomationTest: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test failed: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] org.testng.TestNGException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
[ERROR] at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:341)
[ERROR] at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1030)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:281)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:75)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:121)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:290)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:242)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:121)
[ERROR] Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
[ERROR] at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
[ERROR] at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
[ERROR] at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
[JENKINS] Archiving /u01/Jenkins/home/workspace/Test1/AutomationTest/pom.xml to AutomationTest/AutomationTest/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/AutomationTest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[ERROR] at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
[ERROR] at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
[ERROR] at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:606)
[ERROR] at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:666)
[ERROR] at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173)
[ERROR] at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
[ERROR] at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
[ERROR] at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
[ERROR] at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
[ERROR] at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
[ERROR] at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
[ERROR] at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1162)
[ERROR] at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1056)
[ERROR] at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
[ERROR] at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1570)
[ERROR] at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1498)
[ERROR] at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:268)
[ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:647)
[ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1304)
[ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDTDEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1270)
[ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.setInputSource(XMLDTDScannerImpl.java:264)
[ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.dispatch(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1161)
[ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1045)
[ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:959)
[ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
[ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
[ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:842)
[ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:771)
[ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
[ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
[ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
[ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:327)
[ERROR] at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:195)
[ERROR] at org.testng.xml.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:39)
[ERROR] at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:17)
[ERROR] at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:10)
[ERROR] at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:168)
[ERROR] at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:311)
[ERROR] ... 7 more
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

Comment: Is there a firewall that may block the Jenkins to download packages?

Comment: Thanks for reply, I already check my firewall in server is inactive